# unable to run ionic project in iOS emulator. Getting Permission denied in xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, ionic-framework, permission-denied

When I try to run the Ionic project in the iOS emulator, I got permission error. Please find the error message below.

> copyfile of
>   file:///Users/jathavan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/mCrew-fptfelgfstzgncemgtxqzvgruanm/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/mCrew.app
>   to
>   file:///Users/jathavan/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/81B458E9-9A93-4A3E-88F7-99F72D673A2C/data/Containers/Shared/SystemGroup/systemgroup.com.apple.installcoordinationd/Library/InstallCoordination/PromiseStaging/FF46FA85-7F32-407C-9842-E6F26424EF95/mCrew.app
>   failed: Permission denied

[image]

Answer (score -1):

```
I'm also facing same issue.This is happened because of your permissions override. I completely uninstall the exist xcode Applications. I installed from the start. 
follow the steps it could help you.

1. You should remove these files from your machine.
/Applications/Xcode.app
/Library/Preferences/com.apple.dt.Xcode.plist
~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.dt.Xcode.plist
~/Library/Caches/com.apple.dt.Xcode
~/Library/Developer/Xcode
~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator  

2. restart your computer
3. install again.
```

Comment: Please elaborate on what the issue is here